# How To Disable OS X Mavericks USB autorun

Tags: macos, usb

After inserting USB 3G modem i always getting same behavior:

if bundled software is not installed:

- Opening finder window with mounted folder
- Opening standard installer dialog (agree license, install software that written inside 3G modem)

if installed already:

- Modem-related app is launching

Question: how to disable that "autorun" (not exactly windows-style autorun, i know)?

Super-annoying

P.S. Things applied only to OS X Maverick, previous OSX versions don't show same behavior

UPDATE

- Modem brand is HUAWEI E173
- Previous OSX version don't show same behavior
- Found hidden modem helper, location: `/Library/StartupItems/HWNetMgr`

plist:

```
{
  Description     = "HWNetMgr";
  Provides        = ("HWNetMgr");
  OrderPreference = "Early";
  Messages =
  {
    start = "Starting Huawei HWNetMgr";
    stop  = "Stopping Huawei HWNetMgr";
  };
}
```

And removed it completely && rebooted. Results: nothing actually changed. Same behavior as mentioned above. So i thinking it's not related to the modem brand/bundle and in-system property.

Comment: Does this behavior exists for every user?

Comment: What brand of 3G modem do you use?

Comment: 1) Yes, just created new bare user and still same behavior.


2)Huawei E173

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove the auto launch job with the `launchctl` command.

For example, in my case I have already installed a modem manufactured by ZTE. So I searched for LAUNCHD listings using the `launchctl list` command and grepped for those modem strings.

```
launchctl list | grep -i zte
```

Showing:

```
5681    -   cn.com.zte.usbswapper.plist
```

If you do not find your app, then output all the jobs to a file. This awk command tries to overcome the chance that you may have spaces in your launchd job name.

```
launchctl list 2>/dev/null | awk '
{ x="\""substr($0, match($0, $3), 100)"\""; print x; system("launchctl list " x) }
' > launchList.txt
```

Open launchList.txt. The name of the launchd job will be shown in "..." above the {} block where you hopefully find a "Mobile Partner" or "AutoOpen" string.

Perhaps inspect the item to be more confident before removal. Surround by "" if there are spaces in the job name.

```
launchctl list "cn.com.zte.usbswapper.plist"
```

Then just remove it. This is the command to stop the auto load. Be very sure you are removing the correct agent or deamon.

```
launchctl remove "cn.com.zte.usbswapper.plist"
```

Add it again if you want, using the full path of the PLIST file.

```
launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/cn.com.zte.usbswapper.plist
```

Comment: If you still cannot find the Huawei E173 plist deaemon or agent, can you give the name of the Modem-related application which is launched? Are you able to determine the applications process name?

Comment: Don't have any, betting there are no such thing


`
 % sudo launchctl list | grep -i usb
 Password:
 53 - com.apple.usbmuxd
 43 - com.apple.usbd
 - 0 com.apple.IOBluetoothUSBDFU
 % sudo launchctl list | grep -i zte
 % sudo launchctl list | grep -i huawei
 % 
 % ls /Library/LaunchAgents/
 com.bjango.istatlocal.plist  com.google.keystone.agent.plist  org.macosforge.xquartz.startx.plist org.pqrs.PCKeyboardHack.server.plist
`

Comment: Disabled pgp stuff, not related. Disabled using `move` to different folder + reboot. Again, only `com.apple.*` stuff, nothing more than that (and i thinking it's core system functionality in Mavericks).

`ps aux|grep usb` shows me
   
* /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDevice.framework/Versions/A/Resources/usbmuxd -launchd
* /usr/libexec/usbd

Comment: If that helps: In-modem software named "Mobile Partner.app" and (if not installed) after inserting usb modem i seeing this (visually installer dialog): (ps aux) /Volumes/MTS Connect/Mobile Partner.app/Contents/MacOS/AutoOpen -psn_0_557192

Comment: So you need to find the launchd job which launches the "Mobile Partner.app". I've edited the answer to explain how.

Comment: After further investigation found a hidden helper, see post update. And, more over, nothing did changed without that helper installed. Thanks for investigation and great help. Gonna reward you with that bounty - issue is not resolved anyhow but seems like no one knows anything and you provided best possible insight and your answers could be very helpful to other users

Comment: Well that is the deprecated way of a launch. Read ```man SystemStarter``` to understand if ```/sbin/SystemStarter stop "HWNetMgr"``` works. If so, there is always a way to setup your own launcher to stop the other, read: ```man launchd``` to setup your own "WatchPaths". Lastly check the HUAWEI E173 support site. I see they have a recent 2013 download.

Comment: This answer would be improved if it explained _why_ it's necessary to remove the launch job. Is this really the only way? It seems drastic.

Answer (score 2):

The modem sofware *may* have a hidden "helper" application that launches on user login. This helper application would wait for the USB modem to be inserted and launch the modem software upon insertion.

Check your LoginItems in System Preferences > Users & Groups > User > LoginItems.

*(I would have made the above info a comment/question but my rep score only allows answers not comments...)*

Comment: Just checked, "Login Items" are empty. Also, don't think it's related at all since it works this way now and before even inserting 3G modem first time. Can't find anything suspicious in process list as well (ps aux)

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to check in either:

`/Library/LaunchAgents/
/Library/LaunchDaemons/`

This is where software will install its background daemons.  Once you find the plist associated with the vender/software, move the plist file out and reboot.  With any luck, that should be it.

Comment: That's great answer, really like it. Thanks a lot, now i know more about system internals. But, still, not related to the question. More like it's built in functionality.

Checked every file there, disabled some. Nothing suspicious, only regular stuff like google updater or mongodb/redis launchers

Answer (score 1):

You should remove /Library/StartupItems/HWPortDetect and HWNetMgr, and you might want to delete them from launchctl too.

Comment: This is the correct answer. I found `/Library/StartupItems/HWPortDetect/HWPortCfg` running as a background process and killing it disabled the installer from starting up automatically.

Comment: `launchctl remove com.huawei.HWPortCfg.plist` removed it permanently.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Answer (score -2):

Delete /Library/LaunchAgents/HWPortCfg.plist and /Library/StartupItems/HWPortDetect and reboot your system.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.